# Update form of empty table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a profile form, where the user keeps only one record of this and can update their info whenever they want. Firstly, can i use mysql update to update an empty table?
I am trying to set-up the submit to do two functions. Insert or Update, depending if a record exists:

```
if(isset($_POST['update']) && $profile['user_id'] == ""){
    DB::getInstance()->insert_profile(
        $_POST['user_id'], 
            $_POST['fname'], 
        $_POST['mname'], 
        $_POST['lname'], 
        $_POST['profilepic'], 
        $_POST['location'],
        $_POST['tag'], 
        $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['confemail'],
        $_POST['newsletter'], 
        $_POST['height'], 
        $_POST['build'],
        $_POST['eyecolour'], 
        $_POST['haircolour'], 
        $_POST['race'], 
        $_POST['nationality'], 
        $_POST['languages'],
        $_POST['playingage'], 
        $_POST['accents'], 
        $_POST['aname'], 
        $_POST['aagency'], 
        $_POST['atelephone'],
        $_POST['aemail'], 
        $_POST['aweb'], 
        $_POST['facebook'], 
        $_POST['twitter'], 
        $_POST['spotlight'],    
        $_POST['castingcall']);
}

else if (isset($_POST['update']) && $profile['user_id'] != ""){
hcDB::getInstance()->update_profile(
        $_POST['user_id'], 
        $_POST['fname'], 
        $_POST['mname'], 
        $_POST['lname'], 
        $_POST['profilepic'], 
        $_POST['location'],
        $_POST['tag'], 
        $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['confemail'], 
        $_POST['newsletter'], 
        $_POST['height'], 
        $_POST['build'],
        $_POST['eyecolour'], 
        $_POST['haircolour'], 
        $_POST['race'], 
        $_POST['nationality'], 
        $_POST['languages'],
        $_POST['playingage'], 
        $_POST['accents'], 
        $_POST['aname'], 
        $_POST['aagency'], 
        $_POST['atelephone'],
        $_POST['aemail'], 
        $_POST['aweb'], 
        $_POST['facebook'], 
        $_POST['twitter'], 
        $_POST['spotlight'],    
        $_POST['castingcall']);
}
```

This doesn't work, and doesn't give any errors. Any ideas are appreciated.

Sorry heres my insert and update functions:

```
public function update_profile (
$userID,$fname, $mname, $lname, $profilepic, $location, $tag, $email, $confemail, $newsletter,
$height, $build, $eyecolour, $haircolour, $race, $nationality, $languages,
$playingage, $accents, $aname, $aagency, $atelephone, $aemail, $aweb,
$facebook, $twitter, $spotlight, $castingcall){
                $fname = $this->real_escape_string($fname);
                $mname = $this->real_escape_string($mname);
                $lname = $this->real_escape_string($lname);
                $profilepic = $this->real_escape_string($profilepic);
                $location = $this->real_escape_string($location);
                $tag = $this->real_escape_string($tag);
                $email = $this->real_escape_string($email);
                $confemail = $this->real_escape_string($confemail);
                $newsletter = $this->real_escape_string($newsletter);
                $height = $this->real_escape_string($height);
                $build = $this->real_escape_string($build);
                $eyecolour = $this->real_escape_string($eyecolour);
                $haircolour = $this->real_escape_string($haircolour);
                $race = $this->real_escape_string($race);
                $nationality = $this->real_escape_string($nationality);
                $languages = $this->real_escape_string($languages);
                $playingage = $this->real_escape_string($playingage);
                $accents = $this->real_escape_string($accents);
                $aname = $this->real_escape_string($aname);
                $aagency = $this->real_escape_string($aagency);
                $atelephone = $this->real_escape_string($atelephone);
                $aemail = $this->real_escape_string($aemail);
                $aweb = $this->real_escape_string($aweb);
                $facebook = $this->real_escape_string($facebook);
                $twitter = $this->real_escape_string($twitter);
                $spotlight = $this->real_escape_string($spotlight);
                $castingcall = $this->real_escape_string($castingcall);

                $this->query("UPDATE profile SET 
                    fname = '" . $fname . "', mname = '" . $mname . "', 
                    lname = '" . $lname . "', profilepic = '" . $profilepic . "',
                    location = '" . $location . "', tag = '" . $tag . "', 
                    email = '" . $email . "', confemail = '" . $confemail . "', newsletter = '" . $newsletter . "',
                    height = '" . $height . "', build = '" . $build . "', 
                    eyecolour = '" . $eyecolour . "', haircolour = '" . $haircolour . "',
                    race = '" . $race . "', nationality = '" . $nationality . "', 
                    languages = '" . $languages . "', playingage = '" . $playingage . "',
                    accents = '" . $accents . "', aname = '" . $aname . "', 
                    aagency = '" . $aagency . "', atelephone = '" . $atelephone . "', 
                    aemail = '" . $aemail . "', aweb = '" . $aweb . "', 
                    facebook = '" . $facebook . "', twitter = '" . $twitter . "',
                    spotlight = '" . $spotlight . "', castingcall = '" . $castingcall. "', WHERE user_id = " . $userID or die(mysql_error()));
            }



public function insert_profile(
$fname, $mname, $lname, $profilepic, $location, $tag, $email, $confemail, $newsletter,
$height, $build, $eyecolour, $haircolour, $race, $nationality, $languages,
$playingage, $accents, $aname, $aagency, $atelephone, $aemail, $aweb,
$facebook, $twitter, $spotlight, $castingcall){
                $fname = $this->real_escape_string($fname);
                $mname = $this->real_escape_string($mname);
                $lname = $this->real_escape_string($lname);
                $profilepic = $this->real_escape_string($profilepic);
                $location = $this->real_escape_string($location);
                $tag = $this->real_escape_string($tag);
                $email = $this->real_escape_string($email);
                $confemail = $this->real_escape_string($confemail);
                $newsletter = $this->real_escape_string($newsletter);
                $height = $this->real_escape_string($height);
                $build = $this->real_escape_string($build);
                $eyecolour = $this->real_escape_string($eyecolour);
                $haircolour = $this->real_escape_string($haircolour);
                $race = $this->real_escape_string($race);
                $nationality = $this->real_escape_string($nationality);
                $languages = $this->real_escape_string($languages);
                $playingage = $this->real_escape_string($playingage);
                $accents = $this->real_escape_string($accents);
                $aname = $this->real_escape_string($aname);
                $aagency = $this->real_escape_string($aagency);
                $atelephone = $this->real_escape_string($atelephone);
                $aemail = $this->real_escape_string($aemail);
                $aweb = $this->real_escape_string($aweb);
                $facebook = $this->real_escape_string($facebook);
                $twitter = $this->real_escape_string($twitter);
                $spotlight = $this->real_escape_string($spotlight);
                $castingcall = $this->real_escape_string($castingcall);

                $this->query("INSERT INTO profile(
                    `fname`, `mname`, `lname`, `profilepic`, `location`, 
                    `tag`, `email`, `confemail`, `newsletter`, `height`, `build`, 
                    `eyecolour`, `haircolour`, `race`, `nationality`, 
                    `languages`, `playingage`, `accents`, `aname`, 
                    `aagency`, `atelephone`, `aemail`, `aweb`, 
                    `facebook`, `twitter`, `spotlight`, `castingcall`
                    )" . " VALUES 
                    '" . $fname . "', 
                    '" . $mname . "', 
                    '" . $lname . "', 
                    '" . $profilepic . "',
                    '" . $location . "', 
                    '" . $tag . "', 
                    '" . $email . "',
                    '" . $confemail . "', 
                    '" . $newsletter . "',
                    '" . $height . "', 
                    '" . $build . "', 
                    '" . $eyecolour . "', 
                    '" . $haircolour . "',
                    '" . $race . "',
                    '" . $nationality . "', 
                    '" . $languages . "', 
                    '" . $playingage . "',
                    '" . $accents . "', 
                    '" . $aname . "', 
                    '" . $aagency . "',
                    '" . $atelephone . "', 
                    '" . $aemail . "',
                    '" . $aweb . "', 
                    '" . $facebook . "', 
                    '" . $twitter . "',
                    '" . $spotlight . "',
                    '" . $castingcall. "')");
            }
```

and my form...

```
<form id="profile" action="{$HTTP_HOST}admin/profile.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

and the button:

```
<button class="submit" type="submit" value="update" name="update">Update</button>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Without the code for your `insert_profile()` and `update_profile()` methods we can't help in any specific way.  However, you _cannot_ `UPDATE` a non-existant record.  Instead you would use [`INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) if you wish it to be done in one operation without first checking for the existence of the key value.

Comment: Try to echoing one of your $_POST value, if it's echoing the value of the field, then it should be your connection.

Comment: You can update an empty table, the only problem is there will be no records that will match you criteria, since there are no records at all. Hence nothing will be updated.

Comment: @devon93 if you can assure us that $_POST['update'] is correctly set then the code for insert_profile() and update_profile() may have error. Paste them please

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't UPDATE an empty table, you have to have a record which you want to update.

You have another level of abstraction upon basic mysql queries so we can't really help you unless you post what your insert/update functions do.

Anyhow just check if a record exist, if it does, update the record, if it doesn't insert.

Comment: Yes, you can execute an `UPDATE` query on an empty table.

Answer (score 0):

Where does `$profile['user_id']` come from? If you have this value beforehand you must already know whether the user exists or not and so call insert or update accordingly.

If you think you might have `$profile['user_id']` correctly defined and such user does not exists in the table, then you may have a logical issue in other place of your application. You can always check if that user exists with a simple query:

```
"SELECT user_id 
    FROM your_user_table 
    WHERE user_id = '" . (int)$profile['user_id'] . "'"
```

Comment: I am calling the get_profile function before anything else, but when i try and echo profile['user_id'] it says null.